# Book where a boy races through a cave with deep falls and pits at the climax and I think the villain chases him and falls

Tags: story-identification

This is a very vaguely remembered book I read as a kid in the late 1990s or early 2000s.

I think it is set in our world or something hard to tell apart from it sometime in the 1900s. I believe it was for children or young adults. The main character is male either a boy or a teenager. There is a cave near the town he is in that has huge gaping pits that you basically have to rock climb over so it is scary to traverse. At the end of the book I think he is running from someone and races through this cave terrified he is going to fall to his death. I think his pursuer does fall to his death?

I am also pretty sure that there is some kind of secret old magic or magical item that he has learned about and either found or realized that he knew about the whole time but he himself is not magical.

I think he has either traversed this cave before but very slowly and carefully or he has traversed caves like it before. There might be a dragon that lives in the cave and he goes through the cave to talk to it sometimes or I might be misremembering.

This was definitely part of a series and the next book started with a completely different character in what seemed like a different world, which I think was very cold. I did not read very far into it at the time and have no idea how it linked up.

Even more speculatively. I was reminded of this book while my friend was describing to me the plot of "over sea under stone" where some kids find a secret room by measuring the walls of a house they are in and finding one of the rooms is smaller on the inside than the outside. They make some discovery that starts basically a treasure hunt for some ancient relic and then some people in their town start watching/hunting them trying to take it from them.

I am pretty sure the book I am talking about is not "over sea under stone" but measuring the walls of a house to find a hidden room and this kicking off basically a treasure hunt for some ancient magical artifact seems really familiar and like it might be a part of the book I am talking about.